# Ignoring a specific flake8 rule for a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, flake8

I am using `flake8`, `flake8-docstrings` and many other `flake8` plugins in our project

I want to disable `flake8-docstrings` only for our `test` folder.

I want to avoid running flake8 twice because it would mean that running flake8 wouldn't be the straight forward `flake8 .` anymore. Not only that would mess with my ide settings, that would also be another excuse for the other developers in my project to not run `flake8`.

Is there a way to configure flake8 to exclude specific rules just for a specific folder?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is not currently a native option for this.

There is [a proposal](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues/156) to add support for this in the configuration file, though no current implementation exists.

There is [flake8-per-file-ignores](https://github.com/snoack/flake8-per-file-ignores) which is a plugin that accomplishes this feature

---

**Update:** `per-file-ignores` has been included in core as of flake8 3.7.x

The easiest way to use it is in the configuration file:

```
[flake8]
per-file-ignores =
    tests/*: D101
```

(disclaimer: I am the current flake8 maintainer)

Answer (score 0):

have more complicated case when you need to ignore rule for ALL same named folders of a project
When you have a monorepo with several services and need to ignore a rule for for all files in all `tests` folders accross the "globe"
this way not works:

```
per_file_ignores =
  */tests/*: S101
```